# parse file to list of list in python

Tags: python, list, split, strip

I have a tab separated txt file (file.txt) which looks like this:

```
Barcode1 ID644 79
Barcode2 ID232 80
Barcode3 ID008 09
```

I would like to convert it to list of list:

Expected output:

```
[[Barcode1], [ID644], [79]]
[[Barcode2], [ID232], [80]]
[[Barcode3], [ID008], [09]]
```

I tried this:

```
table_file=open("/Users/file.txt","r")
listID=[]
for line in table_file:
    line = line.strip('').split('\t')
    listID.append(line)
```

However I got something like this for the first line:

['Barcode1', 'ID644', '79\n']
....

Any advice?

Comment: that's a strange format.  Why would you want that?

Comment: because I want to access each element of the list of list so I can do further operations on that, for example I can do something on listID[0][3], listID[1][3], listID[2][3]...on the third element of each list

Comment: I would suggest using something like pandas.  Using a standard tabular data format will pay significant dividends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension on the `line`:

```py
table_file = open("your_file.txt", "r")
listID = []
for line in table_file:
    line = line.split("\t")
    listID.append([[w.strip()] for w in line])

print(listID)
```

Prints:

```py
[[['Barcode1'], ['ID644'], ['79']], 
 [['Barcode2'], ['ID232'], ['80']], 
 [['Barcode3'], ['ID008'], ['09']]]
```